# How to install every thing on from the installation DVD?

Tags: installation, dvd

I have downloaded the dvd (12.04) and I want to sure I have installed every thing on it, so that I may save my INTERNET usage when I need to install new packages.
That is, apt wont download the packages that are already installed.
Any idea ?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: Note that this may result in *more* internet usage, as you will need to download updates for many more packages.

Comment: Even if you cared to Install the packages from the DVD in Future , any-how you will have to Update it , using Entire DVD for installation will cause more BW usage @JeremyKerr mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, all `apt` frontends (`apt-get`, `aptitude`, `synaptic`, etc) will only download a new package if it's not already installed, however, it will download updated packages for anything you've installed, hence, installing everything may actually increase your internet usage.

If you make sure the line starting `deb cdrom:` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` does not have a comment `#` character at the start, and always put your DVD in when trying to install any new packages you want, then `apt` should use the DVD copy if it's still the latest version. Obviously, if there's an update on the internet, it will use that instead.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have actually installed the dvd from a flash disk. there is no line that describes the flash disk repo. in sources.list the deb cdrom: .... is commented out in my sources list.

Comment: Install would treat the flash disk as if it were a CD/DVD so the `deb cdrom:...` line should still point to your installation media, i.e. the flash disk.